# How to get list of impacted C functions from diff between 2 versions of file

Tags: c, unix, diff, clearcase

I am looking for a way how to get list of C functions impacted by the code changes.
Conditions: C project, OS Unix, CVS ClearCase.

Initially, I had planned to use unix diff with --show-c-function option like
diff --show-c-function oldfile newfile

but found that sometime result is incorrect and diff returns functions which were not really impacted by the code changes.

Don't want to write hand-made solution, so, is there any Unix tool which can help to solve this task?